# How can I make a feature with organic groups, spaces, context in drupal 7

Tags: organic-groups, features, 7

I'm trying to build features that behave as follows:

Enabling the feature on the Features tab of the group turns on the relevant create content links, and menu items

Disabling the feature removes the create content link and hides the menu items from the features menu.

Currently enabling/disabling a feature that I have created does not hide/show the create content links or menu items.  If the content was created while the feature is enabled, the view does not go away when disabling the feature.

I have features, context, organic groups, spaces, and purl installed.  I think the issue stems from a missing context.  I would like the feature to be isolated to each group space.